# Como converter str para unicode python

Tags: python, qt

Tenho que fazer uma comparação entre 2 itens, um está em unicode, e o outro está em str, sendo que o que está como str é um array.

```
for bloqueiosPermanentes in arquivo:
    self.blocks.append(bloqueiosPermanentes.replace("\n", ""))
```

é assim que é feito o append na variavel blocks..

depois

```
 for n in j['userList']:
    nicks.append(n['nick'])
```

é assim que é feito o append na variavel nicks, ela recebe seu valor de um arquivo json puxado da internet.

O erro se dá na seguinte comparação

```
for o in nicks:
    if o==self.lblNick.text(): << dá erro aqui na comparacao dos formatos
        pass
    else:
        if o in self.blocks: <<< dá aqui o erro aqui na comparacao dos formatos
            pass
```

Já tentei usar .toUtf8() e unicode(variavel) mas nenhum deles surtiu efeito todos nao sao permitidos

Comment: Se puder passar uns exemplos das entradas seria uma boa para testarmos possíveis soluções.

Comment: Tente colocar uma print do error

Comment: Dá erro ou dá `False` ?

Comment: Especifique se está usando Python 2 ou Python 3. String e unicode tem bastantes diferenças entre essas versões.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter o valor `str` para `unicode` assim:

```
self.blocks.append(unicode(bloqueiosPermanentes.replace("\n", "")))
```

Ou você pode fazer essa conversão na hora de comparar:

```
if o == unicode(self.lblNick.text()):
# ...
if o in map(unicode, self.blocks):
```